# Something like a graph with "multi" vertices

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology

Is there a name for the following structure?

Let $U$ be a set. Let $E$ be a set of finite subsets of $U$.

I consider a labeled directed graph whose vertices are elements of $E$.

Is there a name for this?

---

Note that "paths" in this structure are $p_1\dots p_n$ where $p_i$ are labels of edges and $\operatorname{Dst}p_i \subseteq \operatorname{Src}p_{i+1}$.

Comment: Sounds like an [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: @BillO'Haran No, obviously it is something other

Comment: Do you specify what edges in this graph are?

Answer (score 0):

Well, $E$ is a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) ordered by $\subseteq$, because $\subseteq$ is reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive. Posets can be drawn as [Hasse diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram), and your $p_i$'s are the (graph) edges of a diagram.

Comment: It is not a Hasse diagram for example because it may be not a transitive reduction. I also need to deal with cycles